# How to fix this strange security policy issue in production while it works fine locally?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, blob, ecmascript-5, content-security-policy

I am getting the following errors on production while it works fine locally. The point is that I am fetching pdf from the backend and displaying it inside the component with iframe. In the local it displays fine while after the deploying I faced to these issues...

Refused to frame 'blob:example.com/...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com. Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Not allowed to load local resource: blob:example.com

Here is my code:

```
 <iframe
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          type="application/pdf"
          :src="file"
        />
    axios(`${apiURL}/pdf`, {
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob' //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
    })
    .then(response => {
    //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
        const file = new Blob(
          [response.data], 
          {type: 'application/pdf'});
    //Build a URL from the file
         this.file = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

How can be this fixed?

Comment: It looks like your production uses a setup with Content Security Policy not set properly. Provide more info what type of server to do use (Apache/NginX, do you use Docker, etc.).

Comment: This seems very familiar... so (again): why not set the PDF's url as frame src?

Comment: @ChrisG what do you mean? It's displayed inside iframe. I am not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Why go through all the axios/Blob trouble when you can simply do this: https://jsfiddle.net/obqph8m1/

Comment: Because I am getting pdf from api in different unreadable format so it should be converted into file.

Comment: @0leg I am not sure I don't have access to backend. Is there any way to fix this in front end?

Comment: What do you mean, "different unreadable format"? Judging from your code it's binary data, i.e. the PDF file.

Comment: Look, I tried the axios code with the dummy PDF and it worked fine, which means if this works for you, then the server is sending binary PDF data, which your code implies anyway. Which means you can *simply set the PDF url as src for the iframe*.

Answer (score 4):

`URL.createObjectURL(file)` creates a blob:-url, so you need to allow `blob:` source in you CSP. At least:

```
default-src 'self' blob: https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com
```

But there is an additional notes:

To place all sources into default-src is a bad practice. It reduces CSP efficiency and sooner or later you will step on Firefox's bugs due a fallback to default-src. Therefore much better to use:

```
default-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com;
frame-src 'self' blob:;
```

As I can see, you use Google Tag Manager(GTM) and Google Analytics(GA). GTM requires much [more sources](https://csplite.com/csp/svc109/#CSP_rules) to be allowed, GA - [too](https://csplite.com/csp/svc6/#CSP_rules).

If you'll put all these sources into default-src - you'll have a trouble to manage it. GTM is used to connect other scripts - you will have a lot of sources mixed in default-src.

Comment: Thanks for answering where should be placed above code?

Comment: It depends what software used to build app. You publish CSP `default-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com` somewhere via HTTP header or meta-tag. If you use Helmet here is instructs https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Content-Security-Policy . It need to know what kind of soft do you use on production.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full info on CSP here (including possible fixes):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

You might need to talk to the people responding for the back-end (your company engineers or service provider) to setup up the server properly

If you need a quick fix in the meantime, you can try to use a browser extension to ignore it (e.g. something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en).

Comment: If it's related to backend then how is it working in local which is also connected to the same backend.  And when you copy url from console and paste separately in production then production also works but doesn't  work when it tries to open inside the same page in production